# SQL Query SUM for each date from first date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have searched all over and this is driving me crazy. Let's say I have two fields: actiondate and qty.  Here is a sample of the data:

```
  actiondate        qty
  4/22/2016          2
  4/23/2016          7
  4/23/2016          4
  4/25/2016          9
  4/26/2016          6
  4/26/2016          3
  4/26/2016          4
```

I want to group on the action date, and sum the qty from the beginning date, like this:

```
  actiondate       qty
  4/22/2016         2
  4/23/2016         13
  4/25/2016         22
  4/26/2016         35
```

I sincerely appreciate anyone's help on this.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: The `sum(...) Over(order by ...)` isn't available for you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is quick version:

```
select actiondate, (
    select sum(qty)
    from table t2
    where t2.actiondate <= t1.actiondate) as qty
from table t1
group by actiondate
```

Comment: "Quick" in what sense? Not execution time if the table is large.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've spent 3 seconds to write it

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+:

```
SELECT  actiondate,
        SUM(total) OVER (ORDER BY actiondate) running_total
FROM    (
        SELECT  actiondate, SUM(qty) total
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                actiondate
        ) q
```

In SQL Server 2008:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  actiondate,
                SUM(qty) total
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                actiondate
        )
SELECT  q1.actiondate, SUM(q2.total)
FROM    q q1
JOIN    q q2
ON      q2.actiondate <= q1.actiondate
GROUP BY
        q1.actiondate
```

Comment: Explicitly specifying `rows unbounded preceding` gives better performance in SQL Server BTW. And you also don't need the derived table. `SELECT  actiondate,
        SUM(SUM(qty)) OVER (ORDER BY actiondate rows unbounded preceding) As qty
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY actiondate` would work.